# Docker Volume Permissions with Apache httpd.conf file

Tags: linux, docker, permissions, docker-volume

Working on learning linux, Docker, and Docker Volumes. I want to spin up an httpd container that references a `httpd.conf` file on my local machine that has proxy and load balancing code in it with the correct modules loaded. I've gotten it figured out manually, but now I want to try using a volume to simplify the process.

My issue is I'm getting permission errors when trying to run the container. I'm using CentOS 7 on a VM, and I'm getting an `SELinux Alert` when I try to start up the container. I believe this is a permissions issue, I've changed permissions on my local machine so that the directory and `httpd.conf` file are accessible to anyone, but I believe the actual issue is within the httpd containers permissions.

How do I allow the volume to work? Please let me know what other information to provide if what I have here is too vague, still learning linux and docker so not sure what else will be required to diagnose this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Docker reference [manual](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-the-selinux-label), you can add an additional option to the mount parameter which modifies the SELinux label to the host file/directory being mounted.

So your volume mount parameter will go from something like:

```
-v /folder/to/mount:/directory/in/container
```

To:

```
-v /folder/to/mount:/directory/in/container:z
```

Full command line example:

```
docker run -d --name my-httpd-cont -ti -v "$(pwd)"/httpd.conf:conf/httpd.conf:z httpd:latest
```

As you're learning Linux, you can turn SELinux off, or put it into permissive mode which will log warnings, but won't act upon them. This can be done by running the following command.

```
setenforce 0
```

To turn it off altogether, manually edit the /etc/selinux/config file and reboot the server.

Comment: this worked, I really appreciate the response! going to look over that reference manual a little more now.